# Trigger JavaScript function using SharePoint designer workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, designer-workflow

I wanted to trigger a JavaScript function, whenever a specific workflow attached to a list runs. Or a solution which can trigger a JavaScript function periodically (like-- weekly, monthly). I can not write anything server side not even in SharePoint designer page in inline coding. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

JavasScript is client-side script. It is not possible to be triggered by workflow (which is a server-side logic)

You may put your JavaScript in a SharePoint page. Then script your PC to open that page with IE.

Maybe you can tell us what are you trying to achieve periodically?